# How to remove has_one association in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, belongs-to, has-one

There are related models:

```
class ItemOwner
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_one :item
end

class Item
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :item_owner
end
```

I tried to link Item to ItemGroup. And then I tried to link another Item.

```
2.5.1 :001 > owner = ItemOwner.create
 => #<ItemOwner _id: 5d7b80ff8329b56e1e4383f8, > 
2.5.1 :002 > owner.create_item
"item_owner_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5d7b80ff8329b56e1e4383f8')}], "ordered"=>true}
 => #<Item _id: 5d7b81188329b56e1e4383f9, item_owner_id: BSON::ObjectId('5d7b80ff8329b56e1e4383f8')> 
2.5.1 :003 > owner.create_item
"item_owner_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5d7b80ff8329b56e1e4383f8')}], "ordered"=>true}
 => #<Item _id: 5d7b81208329b56e1e4383fa, item_owner_id: BSON::ObjectId('5d7b80ff8329b56e1e4383f8')> 
2.5.1 :004 > owner.reload.item
 => #<Item _id: 5d7b81188329b56e1e4383f9, item_owner_id: BSON::ObjectId('5d7b80ff8329b56e1e4383f8')> 
2.5.1 :007 > Item.all.pluck(:item_owner_id)
 => [BSON::ObjectId('5d7b80ff8329b56e1e4383f8'), BSON::ObjectId('5d7b80ff8329b56e1e4383f8')]
```

Now there are two items in the database and both related to one ItemOwner.

What is the right way to replace one item with another?

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to removing unwanted items. The ends of the spectrum roughly are:

1. Your model definitions are very bare bones. In practice most models have timestamps on them. If this is the case, you can select all items for a particular owner, order by timestamp, then destroy all but the most recent one. This is the easiest approach to use for bulk data fixing.
2. Alternatively you could load all items for a particular owner, inspect each of them manually in e.g. a Rails console, copy attributes to the item you want to keep from other items, save the item you want to keep, then destroy all of the other the items.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you need to do is destroy the `Item` before creating/assigning a new one. The console commands then would look like this:

```
2.5.1 :001 > owner = ItemOwner.create
 => #<ItemOwner _id: 5d7b80ff8329b56e1e4383f8, > 
2.5.1 :002 > owner.create_item
"item_owner_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5d7b80ff8329b56e1e4383f8')}], "ordered"=>true}
 => #<Item _id: 5d7b81188329b56e1e4383f9, item_owner_id: BSON::ObjectId('5d7b80ff8329b56e1e4383f8')> 
2.5.1 :003 > owner.item.destroy
 => true
2.5.1 :004 > owner.create_item
"item_owner_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5d7b80ff8329b56e1e4383f8')}], "ordered"=>true}
 => #<Item _id: 5d7b81208329b56e1e4383fa, item_owner_id: BSON::ObjectId('5d7b80ff8329b56e1e4383f8')> 
2.5.1 :005 > owner.reload.item
 => #<Item _id: 5d7b81188329b56e1e4383f9, item_owner_id: BSON::ObjectId('5d7b80ff8329b56e1e4383f8')> 
2.5.1 :006 > Item.all.pluck(:item_owner_id)
 => [BSON::ObjectId('5d7b80ff8329b56e1e4383f8')]
```

Note that the diff is the 3rd command (`owner.item.destroy`)